# Choose YouTube videos quality in IINA?

Tags: youtube-dl

[IINA](https://lhc70000.github.io/iina/) is a good player.
You can even play videos from YouTube (via `youtube-dl`)
But how to choose videos quality?

By default `youtube-dl` uses best possible quality. If video is 4K – you'll get 4K. Sometimes it is overkill for notebooks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can configure youtube-dl inside of IINA.

[image: IINA settings page 2020]

To set up max qulity of youtube videos:

1. Go to Settings / Network / Youtube-dl
2. Write in `Raw options` section

   `format="bestvideo[height<=?1440]+bestaudio/best[height<=?1440]"`

   Where `1440` is maximum height that you want (it equals to 1440p).

   This parameter tells player:

   - `bestvideo[height<=?1440]` — to pick best video up to width=1440px
   - `+bestaudio` — mix it with best audio available in source.
   - `/best[height<=?1440]` — if something goes wrong - take just best video&audio pair (under 1440px of height)
3. Restart IINA

---

You can view more details about format selction [in `youtube-dl`documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection-examples)

Also you can read documentation for [IINA & `youtube-dl`](https://github.com/lhc70000/iina/wiki/Use-youtube-dl-with-IINA)

Comment: This format spec will break whenever you play a video on a service that does not split videos (which is actually most of them). Better stick a `/best[height<=?1440]` at the end.

Comment: @phihag OK! fixed answer

Comment: Hint: If you don't want to use bandwith for video when listening music in the background, (radio, mixes, playlists) use `format=bestaudio` (or whatever you prefer :).